# Cannot set web-uri with gradle ear plugin to inclue war from maven repository

Tags: gradle

I'm using gradle-1.7 and trying to create ear with war file from maven repository.

```
dependencies {
  deploy group: 'aaa', name: 'bbb', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

This successfully download war file from maven repo and bbb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war is included in the generated ear file. However, the generated application.xml file is as the following:

```
<module>
  <web>
    <web-uri>bbb</web-uri>
 ...
```

How can I fix the web-uri node to include full war file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the EAR plugin you can specify the web context for a war file.

```
ear
{
   deploymentDescriptor
   {
      webModule( "war name", "/context")
   }
}
```

But to know the version number of the war file is not just a property you can lift from the war project. You have to create it yourself.

```
  web = project("war project")
  value = web.name + '-' + web.version + ".war"
  webModule( value , "/context")
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I did not check stackoverflow account recently. I'll try your  suggention. Thanks!