# Building an EAR file with Gradle: How to configure the webmodules if they are SNAPSHOT dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, wildfly, ear

I create an EAR file from external dependencies using Gradle like this:

```
...
dependencies {
...
    deploy group: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', name: 'war-name', version: '0.3.0', ext: 'war'
...
}

ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        webModule("war-name-0.3.0.war", "/war-name")
    }
}
...
```

The ear Configuration achieves the goal to not have the version number in the path of the HTTP-Endpoints. This solution is suggested in [Cannot set web-uri with gradle ear plugin to inclue war from maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305814/cannot-set-web-uri-with-gradle-ear-plugin-to-inclue-war-from-maven-repository).

So far, everything works just fine. However, if I do the same for a WAR file with a SNAPSHOT version, the configuration of the webModule does not work anymore, since the filename of the war file contains the timestamp of the SNAPSHOT, rather than being called exactly like the version:

```
...
dependencies {
...
    deploy group: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', name: 'war-name', version: '0.3.0-SNAPSHOT', ext: 'war'
...
}

ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        // This fails, because the war file does not have this exact name, but instead contains 
        // the timestamp of the SNAPSHOT's buildtime.
        webModule("war-name-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war", "/war-name")
    }
}
...
```

If I do the above, the resulting `application.xml` contains the following entries:

```
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>war-name-0.3.0-20200714.134805-4.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>war-name-0.3.0-20200714.134805-4</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>war-name-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/war-name</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have it generated like this (basically a mix of the two module declarations above):

```
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>war-name-0.3.0-20200714.134805-4.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/war-name</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
```

I guess I need to find out the used timestamp and then do it like this:

```
ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        webModule("war-name-" + TIMESTAMP_OF_SNAPSHOT + ".war", "/war-name")
    }
}
...
```

However, I am a bit lost on how I could find the timestamp of the exact SNAPSHOT-Version which is packed into the EAR. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a solution myself by now.
What you can do is finding the used War-File by searching the configuration:

```
ear {
    // Since we use SNAPSHOT-Versions sometimes (e.g. for integration testing),
    // We cannot just use the version of the war files when specifying the webModules.
    // Instead, we have to find out the exact filename of the used war-file (which will have an
    // arbitrary timestamp in the case of SNAPSHOT Versions).
    final def actualWarFileUsed = configurations.getByName("deploy")
            .filter{ final dep -> dep.name.contains("war-name")}
            .getSingleFile()
            .name

    deploymentDescriptor {
        webModule(actualWarFileUsed, "/war-name")
    }
}
```

Maybe this helps someone with the same problem.